# What does “Call things by their name” mean?

Tags: meaning, cliche

The Washington Post’s (August 12) article that came under the headline, “Emperor offers a regal critique of Japan’s drift away from pacifism” wraps up with the following episode:

> “Earlier this year, as Merkel visited Japan she gave some veiled
>   advice (to Prime Minister, Shinzo Abe): Saying that Germany was only able to build a good relationship
>   with neighbors by **calling “things by their name**.”

I’m not able to find the definition of the phrase, “call things by one’s (proper) name" - which is shown in quotes - in English dictionaries at hand, nor by googling.

http://www.goodreads.com.quote cites an axiom, “The beginning of wisdom is to call things by their proper name.” as Confucius’ saying.

Google Ngram shows that the phrase has been current since around 1880.

What does “call things by their name” mean? Does it mean to be straightforward or honest?
Is it something like “Call spade a spade”?

Additionally what is the origin of this cliche?

Comment: To quote @Tushar Raj at the near-dupe,  'tell it like it is'.

Comment: "To call things by their own names" has been around for a very long time, much earlier than 1880.

Comment: Avoid euphemisms and obscure terminology.

Comment: (Ie.eschew obfuscation.)

Comment: It's not a cliche, it's an idiom. A cliche means that a phrase is overused.

Comment: One of my favorite quotes: "Always use the proper name for things. Fear of a name increases fear of the thing itself."  (J.K. Rawling viz Albus Dumbledore)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short and simple, being blunt and speak the truth . Yes it is similar to "Call spade a spade".

Answer (score 6):

Here is Confucius's own exposition, provided [via Peter Hitchens](http://hitchensblog.mailonsunday.co.uk/2014/03/calling-things-by-their-proper-names.html):

> If names be not correct, language is not in accordance with the truth of things. If language be not in accordance with the truth of things, affairs cannot be conducted successfully. When affairs cannot be conducted successfully, propriety will not flourish. When propriety does not flourish, punishments will not be properly meted out. When punishments are not properly meted out, the people will not know how to conduct themselves.’

In the context of relations between Germany and other nations, Merkel is suggesting that frankness and clear speech about contentious issues actually opens a way forward to trust and respect, when compared to an approach of avoiding embarassing subjects for the sake of harmony.

Comment: [If you pay too much for cable, you get dejected. If you get dejected you need some comfort ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9vbXpMKz6I)

Comment: Communication breaks down without protocol and objective truth?

Answer (score 3):

As I searched the quote "The beginning of wisdom is to call things by their proper name." I found its original Chinese is 名正才能言順, which corresponds to the four-character [*chengyu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengyu) 名正言順 *míng zhèng yán shùn* in modern Mandarin. It literally means legitimate name, smooth wording, so it figuratively and actually means "legitimate" or "perfectly justifiable". It's often used to indicate the authenticity of a quality or title someone holds, say, a 名正言順 wife indicates she is the genuine wife of the husband married through a series of customary and legal procedures, a 名正言順 PhD is a title gained through genuine ways, and so on. Although this is in the Chinese context, I think it's also applies in this context.

Comment: Sadly, we sometimes have to resort to 'contrastive focus reduplication' in this age where even legitimate names have lost their pedigree. Thus 'coffee coffee', not the muck that ...

Comment: @Ivan H.Jc. It's interesting input. Would you tell me in which chapter of Confucious analects is the Chinese phrase you  mentioned included?.I'd like to find the phrase in its original context.

Comment: @YoichiOishi I saw it on Wikitionary https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Confucius

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My hair was literally literally on fire!

Comment: @ErikE Brilliant.

Comment: @Ivan H. Jc. I found Confucius’ word, you mentioned in book 3 (Zilu 13) of his analects. Confucius teaches his disciple, Zilu - that if the name is not proper, words are not proper. If the words are improper, affairs don’t go well. If affairs don’t go well, propriety and music decay. If propriety and music decay, punishment won’t be rightly executed. Where punishment isn’t executed rightly, people are insecure and worry about where they can rest their hands and legs.

Comment: Cont'd: I wonder if the proverb, "Call tings by their name" is really relevant to the Cofucious' words as being suggested by goodread com.

Comment: @YoichiOishi: There is an interesting related article in Wikipedia under the heading "[Rectification of names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectification_of_names)." I recall from the work of the [Legalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legalism_%28Chinese_philosophy%29) philosopher [Han Fei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_Fei) that he put great stress on maintaining clarity and accuracy between the thing named and the name assigned to it; in the Burton Watson translation of _Han Fei Tzu_ that I read, this effort was called "rectification of names."

Comment: ＠Sven Yargs. I’m impressed to find the name of Han Fei whose name is known by only select group of connoisseurs of classic Chinese philosophy and political theories today in EL&U site. Han Fei is not so popular in Japan as Confucius, Mengzi, Lao-zi, Chuang-tsu, Sun-tzu and Hsub-tzu,  HanFei’s teacher. I've never read any one of his books including “Solitary anger,” “Theory of persuasion,” “Difficulty of persuasion,” “100,000 and more words,” but I know he was the master of logic, communications and persuasion who died a tragic death, through the story of Han Fei in Si-ma Qian’s “History.”

Comment: Cont'd:  I’m interested in reading the part of Han Fei dealing with the clarity and accuracy between the thing named and the name assigned to it you mentioned in either Japanese translation, or in the Burton Watson translation when Japanese translation is unavailable in bookstore, or through Amazon.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: From [_Han Feizi: Basic Writings_](https://books.google.com/books?id=yUgCYEmzMmQC&pg=PA36&dq=%22when+names+are+correct+things+stay%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIhdaS0dW0xwIVWH6ICh3VHgmS#v=onepage&q=%22when%20names%20are%20correct%20things%20stay%22&f=false): "Use the single Way and make names the head of it. When names are correct, things stay in place; when names are twisted, things shift about. Hence the sage holds to unity in stillness; he lets names define themselves ... When names and results match, then superior and inferior will achieve harmony."

Answer (score 1):

It means to refer to things using the most accurate word, even if it's hurtful, awkward, or uncomfortable, instead of using euphemisms or dancing around the subject.

http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic55704.html

In regards to the Confucius quote, I think that has more to do with his philosophy, rather than the English phrase. But I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I feel I should point out that this is not an English phrase as such but rather the literal translation of a German idiom. The German phrase is "die Dinge beim Namen nennen". Some functional translations would be: "to discuss a difficult topic directly" or "to address uncomfortable topics head-on".

Answer (score 0):

The proper name will reflect Aristotle's Four Causes:

Material Cause - the stuff out of which something is made.
Formal Cause - the defining characteristics of (e.g., shape) the thing.
Final Cause - the purpose of the thing.
Efficient Cause - the antecedent condition that brought the thing about.

Key Quote: *"How many legs does a dog have if you call it's tail a leg?"*

This is an example of an improper name. Abe Lincoln answered this question:

*"Four. Calling a tail a leg does not make it a leg."*

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a bit different from "calling a spade a spade". It makes me think of how, in a philosophical debate, the two parties should first agree on definitions of relevant key terms. Socialists and Capitalists see and define Socialism and Capitalism differently. So for a socialist and a capitalist to have a productive debate, they first need to agree on neutral, working-definitions of those key terms. The agreed upon definitions would act as scaffolding between the two parties in order to build the bridge during the debate. Without doing so they would be effectively speaking different languages and wholly unable to understand each other.

In order to discover or establish wisdom (the truth), they must first call things by their proper name.

Answer (score -4):

It means you cannot possibly find a solution to any problem if you have not first become aware of and identified it.